# Unflattening hierarchical data from CSV in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a CSV file with values like

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4
1  2  5  6
7  8  9  10
7  8  11 12
```

i.e. `a` and `b` are attributes of a "parent" entity and `c` and `d` are attributes of a "child" entity.

I read the CSV into a pandas `DataFrame`. How can I then "unflatten" this data so it is stored efficiently and accessible via parent/child semantics?

If `a` is the identifier of the "parent" entities and `c` is the identifier of the "child" entities then it makes sense to create a `MultiIndex` over `a` and `c` but how can I associated the `b` column with the first level of that index and the `d` column with the second level of that index?

All the examples I can find, and the answers to similar questions on StackOverflow, suggest adding `b` to the `MultiIndex` but that seems inappropriate as it is an attribute of the "parent" entities, not an identifier of some intermediate entity between parents and children.

Comment: Would anybody who has downvoted this care to explain why they downvoted?

Comment: Hi, could you show what the unflattened data should look like or how you would access it via parent/child semantics?